# Firebase/firestore trigger a lot of functions at once on larger scale

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm familiar with firestore triggers, https triggers, scheduler functions... all work nice, for one specific path, or one specific task...

But... now I want to do some data synchronization for multiple documents in different paths.

My first idea would be to use google cloud scheduler functions, this would be perfect to sync based on one collection/doc. But if the number of collections increases, the function will need more time to execute. So if this grows to 100 or 1000 different collections with different settings, I need to come up with a different approach. Somehow I want to split this up in 1000 different triggers.

What are your ideas/solutions?
Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to split this up in 1000 different triggers.
```

You probably don't wanna do that. See the limits here [Limits on background functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#additional_quotas_for_background_functions).

```
But... now I want to do some data synchronization for multiple documents in different paths.
```

If this is your only requirement, take a look at [Transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).

With this, you can perform multiple reads and writes on separate or same documents in one go (remember that the operations will be atomic).

A single transaction can contain at most 500 reads and 500 writes, batched writes can contain at most 500 writes. And then of course you can perform multiple transactions or batched writes in the same cloud function.

And if it still doesn't meet your scalability criteria, just call regular http functions from where you are making the changes to documents (not ideal but they can scale beyond the point that database write limits should be your only concern).

EDIT: Based on your comment, here is what I understand:

1. Get a document
2. Make request to an external API
3. Write to a document
4. Repeat above steps for 1000 or more of your clients

Since you said those 1000s need to be done "at once", I'm assuming you are the one initiating the process, but ofcourse the method is generic enough to be modified into something else.

Here is the most efficient way to do that:

Write an http function (prefer "oncall" instead of "onrequest" if you want ease in implementing security).

```
exports.updateclientdata = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
// context will contain data about who sent this request, so you can perform security check here (like who initiated this function)
  let client = data.client;
  let doc = await documentRef.get();
  let externalRequest = await call to your external API and perform operations
  let updatedoc = await updatedocRef.set(your new data);
  return;
});
```

And this is how you'll use it:

Create an array of all your clients.

```
clientarray.forEach(element =>{
var updateclientdata= firebase.functions().httpsCallable('updateclientdata');
addMessage({client: element});
});
```

All of these will run in parallel and can handle array of more than 1000. In JS, use Promise.all to capture event when every function call is resolved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and time. Okay, so there are limits... but how to approach this then? It's not only about a document. In every document are the settings of a client, with these settings I need to synchronize third party data. So every function will do: read firestore data, make external request, write firestore data. How to sync data of 1.000 clients at once then? Transactions is not suitable for this 'problem'.

Comment: See the updated answer and feel free to correct me if I made the wrong assumptions, or if you want to add further info.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot... I'm looking into .onCall now (never heard of it before). Goal is indeed to initiate a lot of functions 'at once'. At once can also be within a minute... So there is some time to spread things. 

Your approach is totally new to me. And promise.all (or promise.any in future) went already through my mind. But I thought writing a batch to update every document that needs to run this function. And then make use of .onUpdate(). But probably I will hit the limits earlier then.